# I need to connect an Individual to a Class through an ObjectProperty, but can't because OWL-DL does not allow it. Is There a workaround for this?

Tags: owl

I am building an ontology that describes some web services. How should I express the following OWL-Full statements in OWL-DL:

```
:Service         a           owl:Class
:Location        a           owl:Class        

:hasInputType    rdfs:domain :Service
:hasInputType    rdfs:range  owl:Class

:Service1        a               :Service
:Service1        :hasInputType   :Location
```

Comment: What are you trying to say by the statement ":Service1 :hasInput :Location"? loopasam's answer is probably along the lines of what you need, but it depends on what exactly you're trying to say.  Does :Service1 actually have the class :Location as an input, or does it have instances of :Location as inputs, or …?

Comment: I ultimately wanted to express that `:Service1 :hasInputType :Location`, and this is different from saying that it has an instance of location as input because the latter implies that there is some instance of `:Location` that is the input to `:Service1`. I should have named the predicate better, I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Does "Service1 hasInputType Location" mean that (note hasInputType/hasInput distinction): "for every x such that Service hasInput x, x is a location"?  If it does, then you can say "Service1 a (hasInput only Location)".  This doesn't require that there _is_ actually some Location instance that is an input to Service1, but just that _if_ there is some inputs, then those inputs are Locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OWL 2 DL, you can use a class name as an individual name. This is called "punning". So the following is valid OWL 2 DL:

```
:InputType     a              owl:Class .
:Service       a              owl:Class .
:Location      a              owl:Class, :InputType .

:hasInputType  a              owl:ObjectProperty;
               rdfs:domain    :Service;
               rdfs:range     :InputType .

:Service1      a              :Service;
               :hasInputType  :Location .
```

You could even get rid of the class `:InputType` and simply use `owl:Thing` instead. Note that the third line actually defines two terms: a class called `:Location` and an individual called `:Location` too. These are *two distinct terms*.

Comment: Punning seems to be supported by Pellet. Are there any issues I should be aware of when using punning? For example, I would probably want to filter results depending an whether I'm looking for Classes or Individuals.
`ask { :Location a owl:Thing, owl:Class. }` returns true `true` using Pellet.
`select * where { ?thing a :InputType }` returns both classes and individuals, and one must always remember to filter results in certain cases.

Comment: Does punning work on properties? Suppose I needed to say `:subject :someProperty :someOtherProperty.` can I create an individual with the same id as a property? Is there another technique for properties?

Comment: It seems that pellet can handle punning quite well, this should save me a lot of work. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Punning also works for property <-> individual and even property <-> class, but does not work for datatype property <-> object property, nor for class <-> datatype.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, it is not possible to create a relation between a class and an individual using OWL-DL. So you have to revise the way you represent your domain knowledge, that's the only solution if you want to be able to use reasoners.

Here service instances could be linked to location instances, or you could also describe specific services using classes rather than individuals. You can then create a relation between `Service1` and `Location` using a existential restriction.

Example using individuals:

```
:hasInput rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain :Service .

:Location rdf:type owl:Class .

:Service rdf:type owl:Class .

:Location1 rdf:type :Location , owl:NamedIndividual .

:Service1 rdf:type :Service , owl:NamedIndividual ;
      :hasInput :Location1 .
```

Example using classes:

```
:hasInput rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain :Service .

:Location rdf:type owl:Class .

:Service rdf:type owl:Class .

:Service1 rdf:type owl:Class .

      rdfs:subClassOf :Service ,
                      [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                        owl:onProperty :hasInput ;
                        owl:someValuesFrom :Location
                      ] .
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first example doesn't work for me because it ties the service instance to a location instance which would mean that an instance of Service has to have a constant Location as input. The second example is very interesting, I haven't thought of it before, i'll see if it suits my needs. I was considering making hasInput a data property giving the URI of the class and handeling the types programmatically. For now, I'd rather keep this question open.

Comment: If you believe it's easier to handle the situation programmatically you can also think of annotation properties, doing kind of the same job as data properties but they represent meta information

Answer (score 1):

To say that any input of `Service1` must be a `Location`, but without implying that any such input must exist, then you can add one more type to `Service1`, namely a universal restriction on `hasInput` for `Location`.

```
:Service1
      a       owl:NamedIndividual , :Service ;
      a       [ a       owl:Restriction ;
                owl:allValuesFrom :Location ;
                owl:onProperty :hasInput
              ] .
```

This says that forall `x`, *if* `Service1 hasInput x`, *then* `x a Location`.  It does not imply the existence of an `x` such that `Service1 hasInput x`.

Comment: How would retrieve the input type in this case using SPARQL? The only way I can think of is repeating the last block in square brackets and replacing `:Location` with `?type`.
`select ?type
where {
    :Service1 a [ a       owl:Restriction ;
                owl:allValuesFrom :?type ;
                owl:onProperty :hasInput
              ] .
}`
Is this feasible? Isn't this considered a TBox query? Can Pellet handle it?

Comment: Well, that class expression is a bit complex, so retrieving it through SPARQL will be a little bit more complex.  I think the quickest and easiest thing to do would be to declare some class, e.g., `LocationInputService` as equivalent to the class expression `[ a owl:Restriction; owl:allValuesFrom :Location ; owl:onProperty :hasInput ]`, and then you can say `:Service1 a :LocationInputService`.  That simplifies some of your data.  You can ask `:Service1 a [ a owl:Restriction ; owl:allValuesFrom ?type ; owl:onProperty :hasInput ]` and get `:Location` for `?type`.

Comment: The distinction between TBox and ABox is really a description logic one, and SPARQL is for asking questions about RDF data.  The way that Pellet (and other OWL reasoners) expose data as RDF does raise some interesting questions, but I think you'll be OK in this case.

Comment: Hmm… running some tests to see what I can get Pellet 2.3 to answer with the structure I suggested.  I'm not sure whether it will be able to answer as I suggested.  I'll update if I figure something out.  I still think that in terms of OWL, this the kind of modeling you want, but I'm not sure whether SPARQL is how you'll want to make your query…